# Find position of substring within string with conditions

Tags: java, regex

Given a String

```
String foo = "if (bar = 10 )
{
    if (foobar == 1)
    {

    }

}"
```

I want to find the position of all "if" which does not have another "if" within the opening and closing braces. For the example above, I would want to know the position of the second "if" but not the first "if".

I know I have to use some form of regex but as I am new to regex , I am not too sure how to go about it. I would also accept a non regex answer.

Comment: For the create regex part of your question I'd recommend regex101.com  it provides you basic information about how to build a regex and also testing it

Comment: `foo.lastIndexOf("if (")`

Comment: I would not expect this to be doable with regexes.  Build it out of simple code with `indexOf` and the like.

Comment: How complex can this string be? Can it be nested to any level? Can you have any number of matching if statements at any nesting level? Are there other blocks using `}` in the string?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this pattern will help

```
(\bif\b)[^{}]*{[^{}]*}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/256)